# How to determine whether a UserGroup has Folder Access Permissions

Tags: c#

I have this folder:

```
C:\ProgramData\MyFolder
```

I want to allow Everyone full control of it.  So, I use this bit of code:

```
string folder = @"C:\ProgramData\MyFolder";
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

Which works.

However, before I execute this code I would like to see if the permission has already been set. If it has then I do not want to run the code again.

I am using C#.

Thanks

Comment: To get the current rules you would call [GetAccessRules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.getaccessrules(v=vs.110).aspx) - something like `var existingRules = dSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(SecurityIdentifier))` and then check the returned rules to see if yours exists.

Comment: excellent - thanks :)